# php shell_exec takes longer than cli execution?

Tags: php, curl

I have a php script that executes `casperjs` on my Centos6 as following:

```
set_time_limit(0);
echo shell_exec("casperjs /home/senrioro/senioro.js --url='".$_GET['url']."'");
```

When the script gets running from cli using `php myfile.php` command, It takes less than 3 sec but when i open that file using my browser it takes more than 30 sec and sometimes browser shows me a 504 error . 
My Question is , is there any configuration that i need to do to make my browser php execution closer to cli ? any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You are open for injection by placing user input directly into this. Huge security risk.

Comment: @Enstage i know, just testing on my dev box .